# HTML 5 Canvas jCanvas/KineticJS when image is draggable, canvas/stage is unresponsive for clicks/touch on an iPad

Tags: html, ipad, canvas, kineticjs, jcanvas

I've tried this with both jCanvas and KineticJS. When an added image is made draggable:

```
var image = new Kinetic.Image({
  image: imageObj,
  id: imageName,
  x: parseInt(CoordX),
  y: parseInt(CoordY),
  draggable: true
});
```

The canvas/stage become unresponsive for clicks on an iPad.
The only place where it recognises click/tap is on the border.

Has anyone faced similar issue and how did you resolve this?

Comment: all my images are draggable on an iPad 2, is this the first iPad you're talking about?

Comment: maybe post some more code?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**  @user1950497, for jCanvas, the key to making an image draggable is to make sure to set the **layer** property to **true** (http://jsfiddle.net/dksmiffs/YdPpy/):

```
$("canvas").drawImage({
  source: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/Gadsden_flag.svg/320px-Gadsden_flag.svg.png",
  x: 200, y: 150,
  layer: true,
  draggable: true
});
```

Thanks to @Caleb531 who guided me to the answer in jCanvas [issue #74](https://github.com/caleb531/jcanvas/issues/74).